# Using UIMenuItem from an Objective-C binding project, action selector will not work on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I am using an Objective-C library that has a UIMenuController with a number of UIMenuItem.

The menu items are initialized as

```
UIMenuItem* menuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"Text", @"Tools", stringBundle, @"Text tool name") action:@selector(createText)];
```

where

```
-(void)createText
{
    NSLog(@"Tool::createText");
}
```

On Xamarin.iOS, running the binding project, the menu works perfectly fine.

However, on Xamarin.Forms, with PageRenderer, the same menu no longer handle click event. createText function is not called at all.

Is there anything obviously wrong here?
Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: How did you write the code you showed in C#?

Comment: The Objective-C UIView is added as a subview of a Xamarin UIView. The menu is added on the Objective-C UIView. So it just shows up without any extra code.

Comment: So, could you provide the C# code you init the UIMenuItem? Because the code in your question is in OC.